# SQL Select: Multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Would somebody mind helping me with this?

I'm trying to select all bookings from my table with a start date of today or in the future. The issue i'm having is that I already have a limit (pagination) and sort.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$sql = "
  SELECT * 
  FROM `bookings` 
  WHERE startdate >= $today 
  ORDER BY `startdate` ASC 
  LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
```

Edit: The code above displays all bookings regardless of date, rather than just present/future bookings.

Comment: What, specifically, is not working about this? Do you get an error?

Comment: Please specify error.

Comment: Sorry - It ignores the 'where' and displays all bookings regardless of date.

Answer (score 0):

> WHERE startdate >= $today

Your immediate problem is that you are not surrounding the date variable with single quotes, so you end up with something like `where start_date >= 2020-01-13`. MySQL sees an arithmetic operation (2020 minus 1 minus 13 = 2006) and happily executes it. Now it needs to compare column `startdate` (which is of `date` datatype or the like) to an integer: for this, it implicitely casts `startdate` to `unsigned`: this generates a number like `20200113`, which is much bigger than `2006`. This is not what you intend.

This woud not happen if you were using parameterized queries.

But bottom line, why bother computing the current date from PHP when MySQL has a built-in for that? Just do: `WHERE startdate >= CURRENT_DATE` and you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the generated SQL statement -- the current date in the SQL query should be something like `'2020-01-02'` (including the single quotes). Without the quotes, you'd get weird behavior like the database doing the subtraction and comparing the date against 2020-01-02 = 2017!.